# Is there a way to cancel all style properties set to a certain element in media query without overriding all them again?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am wondering, if i can from media query breakpoints cancel all the properties of a certain element without overriding them all again ??

For example if my question is not well received yet

```
.some-element {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I need to ruin all this style and start over in a certain media query breakpoint without overriding them in this breakpoint.

**How Can this be achieved if possible??**